# $\Lambda^k(A)$ is a trace class operator

Tags: operator-theory, exterior-algebra, singular-values

Let $A$ be a trace class operator. I am trying to understand the proof of ($\|\cdot\|_1$ means the trace class norm)

$$\|\Lambda^k(A)\|_1\leq  \frac{\|A\|_1^k}{k!}$$

I have a proof but I think there is a mistake in it.

In the proof is the followig: $|\Lambda^k(A)| =\Lambda^k(|A|)$ with eigenvalues $\mu_{i_1}(A)\cdots \mu_{i_k}(A)$ for $i_1<\cdots <i_k$ so $$\sum\limits_{i_1<\cdots< i_k} \mu_{i_1}(A)\cdots \mu_{i_k}(A)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum\limits_{i_1<\cdots< i_k} \mu_{i_1}(A)\cdots \mu_{i_k}(A)$$

The equality doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: What is $\Lambda^k(A)$?

Comment: @Aweygan exterior product of an operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $H$. So for an ONB $\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ $$\Lambda^k(A)(\phi_1\wedge \cdots \wedge \phi_k) =A\phi_1\wedge \cdots \wedge A\phi_k$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second summation should probably be without $i_1<...<i_k$, so that would be $k!$ duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain why that is true? Should it be $\sum\limits_{n=1}\mu_{i_n}(A)^k$? Or why is there a ${}^k$

Comment: I still don't understand why this should make sense with the last equality where the definition of the trace class norm is $\|A\|_1^k=(\sum\limits_{j=1} \sqrt{\mu_j(A^*A)})^k$

Comment: I think he mentioned that $\mu_j(|A|)=\sqrt{\mu_j(A^*A)}$. So its $[(\mu_1(|A|)+\mu_2(|A|)+...]^k$.